# php undercontrol replacement

Tags: automated-testing, web

Actually php undercontrol seems to consume a lot of memory so I'm looking for replacement, in order to test a php application.

Comment: Erwan .. an X vs Y type of question is not appropriate as it is argumentative, why don't you try something like "What is a good replacement for php undercontrol"

Comment: I have to agree with Bruce - we need to ask questions that don't necessarily limit the answers. If you're looking for a replacement, don't seed the question with a replacement. On an unrelated note, if Bruce is up (being from Australia) I should probably be in bed (being from the US...) :-O

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's directly relevant or an option for you, but [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects) suggests that [Hudson is a good option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180460/setting-up-a-deployment-build-ci-cycle-for-php-projects/2225613#2225613). And for good measure, here's a [direct Hudson CI link](http://hudson-ci.org/).